# Why is this trigonometric substitution plugged in without the constant?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

[image]

He plugged in back in as 1-sin^2 but shouldn't it be 1-(1/sqrt(7))sin^2)?

Comment: No, he plugged it into $1-7w^2$ not $1-w^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are substituting $w=\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\sin{\theta}$, therefore:
$$\sqrt{1-7w^2}=\sqrt{1-7\cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\sin{\theta}\right)^2}=\sqrt{1-7\cdot \left(\frac{1}{7}\sin^2{\theta}\right)}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}=\cos{\theta}$$

Comment: I see my mistake now, I wasn't squaring the whole value, thanks.

Comment: @cout You're welcome. Yes, sometimes it is easy to forget about that.